# Anyone knows why this code doesn't compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

```
#include<iostream>

class base{
  public:
  virtual void run()=0;
  protected:
  ~base();
};

class derived : public base {
   public:
   void run(){};
   ~derived();
};

int main(){
  std::shared_ptr<base> b;
  b.reset(new derived);
  b->run();
}
```

I have an abstract base class and derived class from it. In main, I define a shared pointer and allocate it with derived type. Then, I use the virtual function. If I comment out b.reset(new derived) then it works fine. The error message is

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "derived::~derived()", referenced from:
>         std::__1::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(derived*) in test-274b97.o
>         std::__1::__shared_ptr_pointer, std::__1::allocator >::__on_zero_shared() in test-274b97.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any answer will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: You didn't define `derived::~derived()`.

Comment: `base::~base()` isn't defined either.

Comment: Technically, it compiles but doesn't link. And yes, it's because you declared, but did not define, your destructors.

Comment: You should probably have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 3):

You did not define destructors for classes base and derived. You only declared them. Also the destructor has to be virtual

Comment: Destructor doesn't have to be virtual in his specific case, though it's a good idea in general.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, it must be virtual in `base` in this case because there is polymorphic deletion (`shared_ptr<base>`).

Comment: @FredLarson: Setting the value of a `shared_ptr` via `reset` stores the type given, in this case a `derived*`.  There is no polymorphic deletion here.  If it were `unique_ptr` you'd be right, but `shared_ptr` is magic.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset "Proper delete expression corresponding to the supplied type is always selected, this is the reason why the function is implemented as template using a separate parameter Y."

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oh wow, I didn't know that. Still gives me the heebie jeebies if the destructor isn't virtual, though.